# Printed instance address looks like constructor

Tags: python, instance, memory-address, construct

I'm developing a Blender add-on with Python, and I'm trying to understand what this printed instance address represents. I asked this question in the Blender forum (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/155614/add-on-dev-different-memory-address-of-operator-instance), but there are not a lot of developers looking at this, so I'm hoping this is more of a general Python concept.

During a few functions of a class, when I try to `print(str(self))`, I get the following string printed:

```
<bpy_struct, CLASS_NAME("CLASS_NAME")>
```

This is the type of string I would expect to see, and actually do see in later functions:

```
<bpy_struct, CLASS_NAME at 0x0000027E223B95C8>
```

I've never used Python anywhere other than within the Blender environment, so my perspective and relative knowledge is very limited. If you are very familiar with Python and this doesn't make sense, then it is likely something very Blender-specific. My guess is that Blender is doing something weird with my class instance, like copying it from one memory location to another, or possibly that the instance is not fully constructed yet.

Comment: Looks like a custom `__str__`. Can you please check what returns `print(repr(self))` of the same object?

Comment: Yes, it looks like I get the same result: `<bpy_struct, WM_OT_fbxg_ovr("WM_OT_fbxg_ovr")>` (where `WM_OT_fbxg_ovr` is my class name). Later on I get `<bpy_struct, WM_OT_fbxg_ovr at 0x0000022E62420468>`

Comment: How do you get it _later_? It can be important.

Comment: During `__init__()` and another function `def invoke(self, context, event):` (used as a sort of setup function - see https://docs.blender.org/api/2.80/bpy.types.Operator.html?highlight=invoke#bpy.types.Operator.invoke), the instance prints like the constructor string, then all functions afterward seem to print normal instance addresses.

Comment: If its not obvious, it's probably something very Blender specific

Comment: I guess that if it is something very Blender specific you shouldn't worry about it much. Normally every class prints its instances as you expect: `ClassName instance at 0X00address`. It is possible to know the instance address after returning the instance from `__new__` method (which is really a constructor in Python, not `__init__`). I can't think of any reason to print it in a way like `CLASS_NAME("CLASS_NAME")`

Comment: Thanks, knowing that helps a lot. I was trying to attach members to the instance, and they were not available in the later functions, which lead to (confusion, then to) me printing the instance address to compare them. I've changed my setup to store states in an external object, which should hopefully have more predictable instancing.

Comment: Just an FYI, I'm now seeing this constructor-like instance string in all functions, all the time. I've been changing the class here and there, so I have no idea what caused it yet. I will add another comment if I ever figure out what it means.